# DB2 LUW - log SQL commands/statements executes by a particular user

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Please let me know the procedure or method to track db2 luw sql commnads executes by a particular user.

How we can achieve it.

Thanks,
Naikum

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one option for this - you are not providing much detail in your question so I keep the answer on a high level as well:

- Db2 Audit (use category EXECUTE and focus audit on user or role)
- Workload Managemnt Monitoring (new workload for this user, activity event monitor to capture SQLs)

Just to mention the two most relevant in my eyes.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your reply, going through two options.